# Creating A Time Range In Excel

Tags: excel, time, range, formula

I'm trying to create a time range using multiple incidents which have occurred at several times throughout the day and night.

So each group has had 2 or more incidents which have occurred at varying times throughout the day and I'd like to create a time frame for each group; say 09:00 - 14:00.  I've tried using MIN and MAX functions which work in a lot of cases, however when things happen over the Midnight things get tricky. For example:

Data:

Incident 1: 18:00 
 Incident 2: 23:00 
 Incident 3: 20:00 
 Incident 4: 03:00 
Incident 5: 02:00

The formula would result in: 18:00 - 03:00.

I'm using an array formula to pull incidents that have a common group number out of a few thousand incidents.  Unfortunately i'm limited to Excel/VBA for this to work.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is perhaps a better example:

[image]

Comment: The first incident happened at 18:00 and the last one at 03:00 (9 hours later) the formula returns 18:00 - 03:00. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Incidents 1, 2 and 3 happen on the first day, while 4 and 5 happen on the next day. How can you even know that? How do you know that all incidents don't happen on one day, or, that you have 1 and 2 on the first day, 3 on the second day, 4 on the third and 5 on the fourth day?

Comment: Sorry, that was poor wording on my part. I meant that the formula I'm looking for would be able to come to that result.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, the date doesn't matter so much.  It's the times that I'm interested in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the following array formula should work:

```
{=TEXT(MIN(IF(($B$2:$B$8>=$E2)*IF($E2>$F2,1,($B$2:$B$8<$F2)),$B$2:$B$8)),"HH:MM") & " - " & TEXT(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$8<=$F2,$B$2:$B$8)),"HH:MM")}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately I don't have any standard time frames to go off of like what you've posted in your formula.  The time frames will vary with each incident group.  

Here's an example: https://imgur.com/4ixAWzd

Each incident group will have a different time frame.

Comment: Hm, and how you link ```GroupNumber``` with ```Incident```? Or do you want to return the time frame within the ```GroupNumber```?

Comment: Yes I was basically doing: =MIN(IF([group range]=W2,VALUE([named time column])))&" - "&MAX(IF([group range]=W2,VALUE([named time column]))).  But again, it doesn't work when you have times that fall over the midnight.

Comment: How can you tell that for example for group 554433 time frame should start at 19:00 instead of 1:00 if no date is available? I would like to say that in this way it is not possible to distinguish between the current day and the next day.

Comment: So the data is crime pattern data of known individuals committing crimes at certain times of the day or night.  I just want to be able to show what times the individual is active. The dates are often several days apart, and aren't important for the results of this analysis.  This is what makes a formula like this more difficult to put together.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK, but you didn't answer my question - how do you determine that  in the example 1:00 is the end, not the start, of the time frame?

Comment: It's just based on one 24-hour day. The start and end times just depend on when the rest of the incidents happen.  For example on my chart above, the instances in 887766 go from 11:00 - 16:00; earliest to latest - and the others fall in between.  In 112233, the earliest hit was 20:00 and the latest was 03:00; so the result would be 20:00 to 03:00.  As in, this perpetrator has historically hit between the hours of 20:00 and 03:00.

Comment: Well, here's 112233 case - why 3:00 is the latest hit? Do you look at the row position? If 3:00 would be before 20:00 then it would be the beginning of the time frame? And 21:00, which is at the very end, is in the same time frame, or in the next?

Comment: Perhaps it is to be assumed that the day begins in some different time, and not at midnight? Eg 8am